# How to build a MultiLabel Classifier?

Tags: classification, supervised-learning, multilabel

Please Someone could help me in my classification's problem ?

I have a dataset described by 7 variables (x1,...,x7),i want to build a classifier that would be able to predict the outputs a, b, c for each instance.

which algorithm should i use ?
How to adapt it to the nature of my variables (qualitative and quantitative) ?

here it's a screen of my dataset (model of classified data).

Thanks everybody !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just started working on a very similar problem. i have been reading some literature and OneVsRestClassifer looks like a very promising algorithm for this..

I am now adapting my dataset to use the below scikit code example for this.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-multilabel-py

Hope this helps.